# Wi-Fi not working on iOS 7.1-7.1.1

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ios

I just have a quick question of anyone with iOS 7.1-7.1.1.
I have been seeing that iOS 7.1-.1.1 is causing internet issues for people using it.
I was just wondering if anyone could confirm or deny this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been on iOS 7.1 since release on the iPhone 5S and have had no issues with network connectivity on Edge, 4G, LTE or WiFi. WiFi switches between home Airport Extreme Base Station powered 802.11n network and the work WiFi powered by Cisco access points also a 802.11n.